# Error: ReadItem: unknown type 32, perhaps written by later version of R

Tags: r, rmysql, rscript

am running a R script through cron for example `R CMD BATCH myRFILE.R myOutFILE.Rout` . When i run this from `bash` it runs successfully , however when i do this through cron for multiple R files i get the following error :

> Error: ReadItem: unknown type 32, perhaps written by later version of
>   R Execution halted

I am also using RMysql in my scripts. Kindly let let me know how can i tackle this as all the scripts from cron are failing intermittently.

Comment: Make sure the environment is the way you need it when cron runs.

Comment: this is something am facing recently, a week back it was running fine.

Comment: I have the same issue as well!! What on earth is that error?!

Comment: Experiencing the same error here... can't even begin to figure where from though